# JavaScript array won't update and can't type anything in inputs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input, uuid

When I click the 'create note' button on my expense manager website the edit page appears but keeps trying to reload and i'm not able to type anything in either of the inputs.

I'm receiving one error: 'Cannot read property 'title' of undefined' and a message: ' Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection'

I expected to be able to create an expense and to see it updated when I returned to the home page however I can't even type anything and nothing will update anyway.

// JS code

```
// Read existing expenses from localStorage
const getSavedExpenses = function () {
    const expensesJSON = localStorage.getItem('expenses')

    if (expensesJSON !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(expensesJSON)
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
// Save expenses to localStorage
const saveExpenses = (expenses) => {
    localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify(expenses))
}

const titleElement = document.querySelector('#expense-title')
const bodyElement = document.querySelector('#expense-body')
const removeElement = document.querySelector('#remove-note')
const expenseId = location.hash.substring(1)
const expenses = getSavedExpenses()
const expense = expenses.find(function (expense) {
    return expense.id === expenseId
})

// Get the DOM elements for an individual expense
const generateExpenseDOM = function (expense) {
    const expenseEl = document.createElement('div')
    const textEl = document.createElement('a')
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button')

// Setup the expense text
if (expense.title.length > 0) {
    textEl.textContent = expense.title
} else {
    textEl.textContent = 'Unnamed note'
}
textEl.setAttribute('href', `expense-edit.html#${expense.id}`)
expenseEl.appendChild(textEl)


// Remove expense by id
const removeExpense = function (id) {
const expenseIndex = expenses.findIndex(function (expense) {
return expense.id === id
})
if (expenseIndex > -1) {
    expenses.splice(expenseIndex, 1)
  }
}

// Setup the remove expense button
removeButton.textContent = 'x'
expenseEl.appendChild(removeButton)
removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    removeExpense(expense.id)
    getSavedExpenses(expenses)
    renderExpenses(expenses, filters)
})
return expenseEl
}
```

```
if (expense === undefined) {
    location.assign('expense-edit.html')
}

titleElement.value = expense.title
bodyElement.value = expense.body

titleElement.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    expense.title = e.target.value
    savedExpenses(expenses)
})
// add new expenses
document.querySelector('#new-expense').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   const id = uuidv4()
      expenses.push({
         id: id,
         title: '',
         body: ''
      })
      getSavedExpenses()
     location.assign(`/expense-edit.html#${id}`)
   })
```

// HTML code

```html
   <input id="title" placeholder="Expense title">
    <textarea id="body" placeholder="Expense body"></textarea>
    <button id="remove-expenses">Remove expense</button>
<script src="expenses-functions.js"></script>
<script src="expenses-edit.js"></script>
```

```html
   <input id="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Filter todos">
     <div id="expenses"></div>
    <button id="new-expense">Submit</button>
    <script src="/uuidv4.js"></script>
    <script src="/expenses-functions.js"></script>
    <script src="/expenses-app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places where you use `location.assign()`, which navigates to a new page.

My guess is this one keeps triggering:

```
if (expense === undefined) {
    location.assign('expense-edit.html')
}
```

`expense` is undefined, so the page reloads; `expense` is undefined, so the page reloads again...

Figure out why `expense` does not have a value. (You can also just comment these lines out to confirm that this is, in fact, the problem.)

---

**update:** Additionally, I think you are assuming variables (like the `expenses` array) persist across page loads. JS variables do not persist across page loads. After you call `location.assign()`, *all* JS variables reset.

So this part of the code doesn't really do anything:

```
expenses.push({
     id: id,
     title: '',
     body: ''
  })
```

I wasn't sure what happens in `getSavedExpenses()`, and thought maybe variables were persisted there via [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or something. (Otherwise that is probably also dead code, since its return value isn't even used.)

There are two ways to persist data across "page loads":

1. Save the data to persistent storage, like a database or localstorage. Then reload the data the next time the page is loaded. If a database is used, usually data from a form is sent via an API request to a database server.
2. Don't reload the page; modify the page DOM via JS (so it might look like the page "reloaded.")

**update 2:**

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

This error is caused by trying to access a property called `value` on a variable with the value `null`. In your code, that is happening in two places:

```
titleElement.value = expense.title
bodyElement.value = expense.body
```

After the error is encountered, JS stops executing. This is likely the reason `localStorage.getItem('expenses')` results in null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that does seem to be a problem because when I comment them out the page loads fine, I just get that error still and the data still isn't saved. I can't figure out why expense doesn't have a value though.

Comment: @RJDdev: I added an update that might give you more insight.

Comment: @RJDdev: If you comment out `location.assign` from the event handler, I think you will see that the data was saved. (It's just immediately discarded on the navigation.)

Comment: @RJDdev: did you comment out the entire line? I now see `getSavedExpenses()` uses localStorage. There is a `localStorage.getItem`. However, there should also be a matching `localStorage.setItem`, perhaps in a method called `saveExpenses()`

Comment: Thanks for the update, I don't quite understand what you mean about persistent data. When I comment out location.assign the website crashes. I have added some code to my question including the getSavedExpenses() function.

Comment: @RJDev: What I meant was if you don't call `location.assign()`, you could confirm that `expenses` did in fact change. With your updates, I am almost positive the root cause of your problem is you are never saving data to localStorage (only reading from localStorage). In other words, the results of `localStorage.getItem()` will never be different if you don't ever call `localStorage.setItem()` at some point.

Comment: @RJDdev: And the call to `getSavedExpenses()` inside the event handler should really be `saveExpenses(expenses)`.

Comment: I have just added that method and added the code to my question. But I am now receiving a different error which I've also added to the question.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand now. I forgot to write that code previously. I have also changed all the calls to that function to saveExpenses().

Comment: @RJDdev: to help you with the new error, we need to see the results of `localStorage.getItem('expenses')`. Apparently there is something wrong there.

Comment: How do I find the results of localStorage.getItem('expenses')?

Comment: @RJDdev: After you load your page, open the browser dev tools and type it into the interactive JS console. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log

Comment: @RJDdev: I think you can inspect the localeStorage contents directly, too: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/localstorage

Comment: I've typed it into the console and it's showing that expenses is undefined.

Comment: @RJDdev: Are you sure you're checking on your app's page? localeStorage is limited to the domain it was created on. A simpler method may be to just add a console.log() inside getSavedExpenses()

Comment: I have added a console.log() in my if statement in the getSavedExpenses() function and it printed in the console. I have also added an image of the console to my question showing what happened when I tried to access localStorage.

Comment: In response to your update, I have changed two of the ID's in my HTML which didn't match up to what I had typed  when I was defining titleElement and bodyElement in my JavaScript. However, I am now getting another error (added to my question).

Comment: @RJDdev: Open a new question. I helped fix a series of new bugs discovered after the previous one was fixed. It is unclear, even to me, which bugs still remain. Stack Overflow questions should cover only one bug/problem. Once solved, accept the solution and upvote any helpful answers. If you discover new bugs after fixing the original problem, open a new question for the new problem. This  helps people understand your question better and you are more likely to get answers. This also makes the answers more useful to people with similar problems. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am 16 and new to coding and stackoverflow so I am just starting to fix bugs on my own but thank you for your help and I will ask a new question if I cannot fix it.

Comment: @RJDdev: Welcome to StackOverflow~ I found another document that explains how to write good questions that attract people who want to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.